# Proving $4^n=\sum_{k=0}^n2^k\binom{2n-k}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

$4^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}2^k\cdot{{2n - k} \choose n}$

I tried formal power series, but failed.

Comment: I feel like this can be done with induction with setting n=1 as the base case and proceeding from there.

Comment: @PloniAlmoni Maybe, but it's not trivial; the inductive step gets messy because the $n$ in the binomial expression changes, so $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}$ term doesn't compare well with the $\sum_{k=0}^n$ term. (Again, it might be doable, but it would require some cleverness.)

Comment: \begin{align}
4^n=(1+1)^{2n}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{2n\choose k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n\choose k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n\choose k+n}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n\choose k}+{2n\choose n-k}
\end{align}

Comment: @MyGlasses I might be totally dense this morning (will try to drink coffee faster) but is it obvious where to proceed from here? In particular, how do we get $2^k$ as a *multiplier* on the back expression?

Comment: Searching [in Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5En2%5Ek%5Cbinom%7B2n-k%7D%7Bn%7D%24&p=1) returns several questions about this sum:
[Closed-form formula to evaluate $\sum_{k = 0}^{m} \binom{2m-k}{m}\cdot 2^k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1509446),
[Solving $\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k \binom{2n-k}{n}=4^n$ using generating functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1916579),
[How to prove that $\sum_{i=0}^n 2^i\binom{2n-i}{n} = 4^n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1782432) ...

Comment: ...and [How prove this $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\binom{2n-k}{n}}{2^{2n-k}}=1 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/508944). (maybe you can find more.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solution through Complex Analysis and the residue theorem.

$$\mathcal{S}(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^k\binom{2n-k}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}2^{n-k}\binom{n+k}{n} $$
is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the product between $\sum_{k\geq 0}2^k x^k=\frac{1}{1-2x}$ (geometric series) and $\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{n+k}{n}x^k = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$ (stars and bars). In particular

$$ \mathcal{S}(n)=\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{(1-2x)\left[x(1-x)\right]^{n+1}},x=0\right) $$
but due to the symmetry of the meromorphic function $\frac{1}{(1-2x)\left[x(1-x)\right]^{n+1}}$ the residue at $0$ and the residue at $1$ are the same number. The only other pole is at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and the sum of the residues is zero, hence $\mathcal{S}(n)=4^n$ can be proved from the straightforward
$$ \text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{(1-2x)\left[x(1-x)\right]^{n+1}},x=\frac{1}{2}\right)=-2\cdot 4^n. $$

Answer (score 8):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n2^k\binom{2n-k}{n}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\binom{2n-k}{n}\tag1\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=j}^n\binom{k}{j}\binom{2n-k}{n}\tag2\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{n+j+1}\tag3\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{n-j}\tag4\\
&=\frac12\sum_{j=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{j}\tag5\\
&=\frac12\cdot2^{2n+1}\tag6\\[12pt]
&=4^n\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: use the binomial theorem to expand $(1+1)^n$
$(2)$: change order of summation
$(3)$: Vandermonde Identity
$(4)$: symmetry of Pascal's Triangle
$(5)$: average $(3)$ and $(4)$
$(6)$: use the binomial theorem to expand $(1+1)^{2n+1}$
$(7)$: simplify

Step $(3)$ is actually an extension of Vandermonde using negative binomial coefficients:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=j}^n\binom{k}{j}\binom{2n-k}{n}
&=\sum_{k=j}^n\binom{k}{k-j}\binom{2n-k}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=j}^n(-1)^{k-j}\binom{-j-1}{k-j}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{-n-1}{n-k}\\
&=(-1)^{n-j}\binom{-n-j-2}{n-j}\\
&=\binom{2n+1}{n-j}\\
&=\binom{2n+1}{n+j+1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Do you see any combinatorial (double counting) proof of the equality ? $4^n=2^{2n}$, so it may have to do with counting the subsets of a set of cardinal $2n$ in a clever way.

Comment: @GabrielRomon: Now that I've seen there are previous questions, the answer that seems the most combinatorial is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/508962).

Answer (score 5):

With formal power series as requested by OP we may write

$$\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k {2n-k\choose n}
= 2^n \sum_{k=0}^n 2^{-k} {n+k\choose n}
= 2^n \sum_{k=0}^n 2^{-k} [z^n] (1+z)^{n+k}
\\ = 2^n [z^n] (1+z)^n \sum_{k=0}^n 2^{-k} (1+z)^k
= 2^n [z^n] (1+z)^n \frac{1-(1+z)^{n+1}/2^{n+1}}{1-(1+z)/2}
\\ = 2^{n+1} [z^n] (1+z)^n \frac{1-(1+z)^{n+1}/2^{n+1}}{1-z}.$$

We get from the first piece

$$2^{n+1} [z^n] (1+z)^n \frac{1}{1-z} = 
2^{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} = 2^{2n+1}.$$

The second piece yields

$$- [z^n] (1+z)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{1-z}
= - \sum_{k=0}^n {2n+1\choose k}
= - \frac{1}{2} 2^{2n+1}.$$

Joining the two pieces we find

$$2^{2n+1} - 2^{2n} = 2^{2n} = 4^n.$$

Answer (score 4):

Another (shorter) way to approach this is

$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  2n - k \cr 
  n \cr}  \right)2^{\,k} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  2n - k \cr 
  n - k \cr}  \right)2^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\,} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  2n - k \cr 
  n - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  k - j \cr}  \right)} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)\,} {\left( \matrix{
  2n + 1 \cr 
  n - j \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 2}\sum\limits_{l\,} {\left( \matrix{
  2n + 1 \cr 
  l \cr}  \right)}  = {{2^{2n + 1} } \over 2} \cr} 
}$$
where the bounds in brackets means that they are implicit in the binomial, and
where in the middle step the *Double Convolution* is used, which is
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{\left( {m\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  a - k \cr 
  n - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k + b \cr 
  k - m \cr}  \right)}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {m\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n - m} \left( \matrix{
  n - a - 1 \cr 
  n - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
   - m - b - 1 \cr 
  k - m \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{n - m} \left( \matrix{
  n - m - a - b - 2 \cr 
  n - m \cr}  \right) = \left( \matrix{
  a + b + 1 \cr 
  n - m \cr}  \right)\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;a,b \in R \hfill \cr 
  \;n,m \in Z \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
}$$

Answer (score 0):

Try formal power series harder. The same [Snake Oil Method](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf) I used to [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507390/generating-function) one of your other recent questions, works here as well. I will let you work through this one on your own with a few hints. Let $B=B(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$ and $C=C(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$ be the generating functions for the central binomial coefficients and Catalan numbers, respectively. Then
$$
B=\frac{1}{1-2xC}, \qquad B^2=\frac{1}{1-4x},
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n+k}{n}x^n=BC^k.
$$
The last inequality can be proved combinatorially: consider all lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2n,k)$ using steps $u=(1,1)$ and $d=(1,-1)$. Then any such path can be written uniquely as $P_0uD_1uD_2u\dots uD_k$, where $P_0$ is a grand Dyck path and $D_1,\dots,D_k$ are Dyck paths, all together (with $P_0$) of total semilength $n$.